# How to get data string from span class and time class Jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

There is the HTML:

```
<div class="td_module_5" >
            ...
<div class="td-module-meta-info">
<span class="td-post-date">
<time class="entry-date updated td-module-date" datetime="2018-08-26T09:16:24+00:00" >26.08.2018
</time>
</span>
```

My code

```
date = doc.select("div.td_module_5 > div > span.td-post-date");
```

Is not working. In final I would to get string "26.08.2018". Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fixed it.

```
date = doc.select(".td-post-date");
```